# CSS gradients not displaying on old versions of IE and Firefox

Tags: css

```
.horizontalTabGradient
{
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#edeff4', endColorstr='#ffffff', iOrientation=1); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#edeff4), to(#ffffff)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #edeff4,  #ffffff); /* for firefox 3.6+ */   
}
```

We set the backgrounds this this CSS specifies to a lot of our buttons and grid headers throughout our app. We recently found through testing that when viewing the app on older versions of Firefox and IE, the background does not appear.

Is this just flat out not supported by the older versions? Or is there a way we can get it to work in both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this just flat out not supported by the older versions?

Yes.

> Or is there a way we can get it to work in both.

Yes, but not with CSS alone, you need to use images.

Comment: Okay that leads me to my next question. Since we have different sizes on all of the headers that use this, I would like to create maybe a 1px image of this gradient, and use background repeat to do it, but what would that CSS look like?

Comment: background: url(/path/to/1pximage.jpg) repeat-x; (or repeat-y if it's a horizontal gradient)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this out. - Actually, what would be the easiest way to obtain a 1px vertical gradient image from the existing gradient. Screenshot the screen is the first step obviously, but then what?

Comment: don't you have the psd file? or even the jpg file? if you can save the jpg, just crop it using photoshop. easy peasy :P

Comment: Well it's actually creating the gradient dynamically, not using an image file. That's what I want to change it to. I think you overestimated by Photoshop skills. Maybe I'll take this one on over to the Photoshop stack ;)

Comment: Try this: http://www.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/2010/dynamically-drawing-gradients-with-php/